# 1 switch-bank, 1 rotary, 5 inputs, 3 devices, no idea how

Tags: switches, rotary

I have 3 separate LCD's which have 5 push buttons to control the LCD settings and power.  All push buttons on the LCD share a common ground.  What I would like to do is use 1 switch bank and a 3-position rotary switch to select which LCD to adjust the settings on, however I'm unable to find an elegant solution via google. due to space limitations, I am unwilling to use a giant multi-pole rotary.  Is there an IC that will handle this?

[image]

Comment: Do your GND lines need to be connected? The obvious choice would be switching the GND lines.

Comment: @Janka The even more obvious choice is to just use a microcontroller for 8 inputs and 15 outputs. Either that or a couple of standard logic gate packages

Comment: When I can just switch the GND lines, I don't need a µC or such. Only 15 diodes and a three-way switch and that was it.

Comment: Are the LCD control lines digital or analog?  A multiplexer for digital, and I think you can do the same with analog switch bank.  I don't have any part numbers on hand.

Comment: All of the control lines are analog as far as I can tell.  I was just drawing out the 15-diode-common-ground idea before I came back to check for an answer.  I think I might go with that and see if it works.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you have to make sure that you can work with ONE lcd, ONE rotary switch, ONE set of buttons, ....

Structuring your code in a modular way helps greatly here. for example, your lcd code would look like this:

```
  lcd_init(LCD1); //initialize lcd1
  if (rotary_read() = ROTARY_2) lcd_puts(LCD3, vBuffer); //display vBuffer on LCD3 if rotary 2 is selected
  btn_state=lcd_readbtn(LCD2); //read the button states on LCD2
```

Comment: Theses are 800x600 LCD driver boards acting as monitors, so I'm not running them through a micro controller.  I'm using the inputs included on the driver boards.  Thank you, though.